# Need To Calculate Heading From Accelerations & Then Rotate Accelerations Accordingly

Tags: math, trigonometry, matrix-multiplication

I am currently building a simple telemetry computer for model rockets. I am using a standard 6-axis IMU which gives me angular rate and linear acceleration. I wish, at startup. to detect the initial heading through only the linear acceleration measured and to then, from that point, rotate the accelerations to align with earth's X, Y, and Z. During the initialization process the only acceleration that the IMU should experience is from gravity.

For experimentation purposes, I have written the code in python, but the end algorithm will be converted to Rust.

The following code is based on the matrix math found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations).

```py
import math

start_x = -0.43557498
start_y = 0.5819724
start_z = -9.900554

# Keep in mind we are using X, Y, and Z rotation and not Pitch, Roll, and Yaw
α = math.atan2(-start_y, -start_z);
β = math.atan2(start_x, -start_z);
γ = math.atan2(-start_x, -start_y);

sin_α = math.sin(-α)
sin_β = math.sin(-β)
sin_γ = math.sin(-γ)

cos_α = math.cos(-α)
cos_β = math.cos(-β)
cos_γ = math.cos(-γ)

end_x = (start_x * cos_β * cos_γ) + \
        (start_y * (sin_α * sin_β * cos_γ - cos_α * sin_γ)) + \
        (start_z * (cos_α * sin_β * cos_γ + sin_α * sin_γ))

end_y = (start_x * cos_β * sin_γ) + \
        (start_y * (sin_α * sin_β * sin_γ + cos_α * cos_γ)) + \
        (start_z * (cos_α * sin_β * sin_γ - sin_α * cos_γ))

end_z = (start_x * -sin_β) + \
        (start_y * sin_α * cos_β) + \
        (start_z * cos_α * cos_β)

print(str(α) + ", " + str(β) + ", " + str(γ))
print(str(end_x) + ", " + str(end_y) + ", " + str(end_z))
```

I expect something close to the following output:

```
-0.05871423859483104, -0.04396665869464738, 2.4990867751753854
0, 0, -10
```

But instead I get:

```
-0.05871423859483104, -0.04396665869464738, 2.4990867751753854
1.3912018089280702, -0.4101017035926812, -9.20680275012796
```

I am fairly sure that the problem lies with the rotation math, as the heading calculation is fairly easy to understand and intuitive.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome Reggieman! I think there's an issue between the frames of reference of your input angles and what the rotation matrix is expecting. The input angles appear to be calculated from the same frame of reference, but the rotation matrix is applying each rotation angle relative to the last rotated frame of reference if that makes sense?

Comment: Yeah I actually converted the entire system to quaternions and fixed the whole issue using a separate method already lol. Thanks though.

Comment: Well done for fixing it!